# Change theme based on loggedin user group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, theme

We have 4 SharePoint group..

We have created 4 .spcolor files. Is it possible to apply theme to sp site based on logged in user group? Or composed look?

I am worried to set composed look as it will effect entire site look for all users. Any solution other then changing css at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option would be to generate respective .CSS files & dynamically load them using some user control in master page. By doing this you do not have to worry about the look effecting other users as it is at browser level (per user session)

If you go with .spcolor, I guess you have to set it to Sp site property & update the site object which obviously will effect all users.

Comment: But for other users the masterpage user control will put their own theme. Isnt it?

Comment: that is what you wanted right. Example SPGrp1 - RED, SPGrp2 - GREEN, SPGrp3 - YELLOW, SPGrp4 - BLUE.

Comment: Yes.. My question was wrt ur para 2

Comment: i was telling (intention was to provide the drawback of the approach too) you to avoid para 2 as it will effect all. go with para 1 (.css)

Comment: Does the css get effected after page load?

Comment: yes the css gets applied and then the page is rendered to client with styles from chosen .css file from user control

Comment: Do you have code example to change css or cssfile